# move obj in A-Frame using quaternion values

Tags: javascript, 3d, quaternions, aframe

I'm trying to move an object in a 3D space using A-Frame.

I'm using the "Euler coordinates" (X, Y, Z) and I'm passing them to the object with the following code:

```
document.querySelector('a-entity[id=obj]').setAttribute('rotation', input.computed.z+ ' '+ -input.computed.x + ' ' + input.computed.y);
```

Everything is working fine.

But now I'd like to implement the same thing but using the quaternions (QX, QY, QZ, QW).

I have some problem in finding a good example or a simple documentation to start with.

Does anyone have some suggestion on I can get the same result as the "Euler coordinates" but with the quaternions?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the quaternion methods used in [threejs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Quaternion).
Then, within a custom made `component` you can either:

Operate on the `<a-entity>` with the `el.setAttribute()` method, 
or You can modify it using the three.js objects: `el.object3D.rotation.set()`.

If You want to directly apply transform matrices, You can get the transform matrix using `this.el.object3D.matrixWorld`(world transform), or `this.el.object3D.matrix`(relative transform), then You can apply a transform matrix to an object using the `applyMatrix()` from the object3D [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D).
To apply quaternion matrices, use `applyQuaternion()`.

I've set up a simple working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/rcfw8wfd/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I'm quite new to this topic so I'm trying to reading the documentation to better understand how it works. I don't understand if there is a way to have a function similar to `el.setAttribute('rotation', z x y);` but with the 4 quaternions values `el.setAttribute('rotation', z x y w);`. Do I have to use **transform matrices**?  As I said I'm learning right now so I have some problems to fully understand

Comment: @Jack As far as I understand, You can get Your xyz position vector, apply the quaternion to it, and rotate it by the xyz output vector. I'd make my own function/component, with the element and quaternion input, which will rotate the element as described above.

Comment: @Jack as far as i know a-frame has no such methods, since it's build on three.js, i'd use three.js quaternion methods.